# Get Latest Version of a post from the Database

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am creating a blog where users can post and other users can edit there posts.

When someone edits a post the version should be updated and saved, this works.

Now I want to display only the latest version to the readers.

Not 100% sure how this should work.

I created a function within the model that would select the version based on a simple MAX query. Here is the model:

```
public function getlatestversion(){
        $lastest = DB::table('contentPost')->max('version');

        return $this->$lastest;
    }
```

My Blade View:

Partial:

```
 {{ Str::limit($post->content_posts()->getlatestversion()['content'], 140) }}
```

Can I use this directly in my blade view? Or should it also be in my controller?
The error that I get is:

> "Call to undefined method... getlatestversion()"

Does it have something to do that it is not in my controller, or am I passing it the wrong way?

Thanks

Comment: Q: I want to get the latest post in the database.  A: Then make sure your table has a "timestamp" column (e.g. "post_date"), and be sure to query "max(post_date)" in a where clause in your select.

Comment: A: We do have that as well, but I want to use my version column. We could do this either way, but the issues still remains that I can't get hold of my method in my view. @FoggyDay Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously in a context, where your method content_posts() does not retrieve a working reference to an object featuring the getlatestverison() method.

Try printr()-ing the result of $post->content_posts() - this might give you a precise hint why you cannot access your method.